# fourier series of $f \circ R_\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I have a problem with the following:

If $f \in L^2 (T)$ and $\displaystyle f(x)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n e^{2 \pi i nx } $ in $L^2(T)$ the Fourier expansion, then why the Fourier expand of $ f \circ R_\alpha $ is given by:

$$ f \circ R_\alpha (x) = \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i nx} e^{2 \pi i n \alpha} $$

where $ \displaystyle R_\alpha(x) = x+ \alpha (mod 1) = \{x + \alpha \}$ ?

$T$ is the $1-$dimensional torus.

I think I am missing something obvious, but I can't understand what.

Thank you!